# How does $ a^{2^i}a^{2^i} $ become $ a^{2^{i+1}} $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I have this expression: $$ a^{2^i}a^{2^i} $$

My slides convert this into: $$ a^{2^{i+1}} $$

I however don't see how to convert $$a^{2^{i}+2^{i}}$$ into that resultant form.

Which math rule am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a^{2^i}\cdot a^{2^i}=a^{2^i+2^i}=a^{2\cdot 2^i}=a^{2^{i+1}}$

Comment: yep, that's it. stupid me, just been staring to much at it and not seeing that basic simplification. Also your right bracket is in the wrong spot, breaking your formula.

Comment: Thanks, a typo :)

Comment: you can also ${(a^{2^i})}^2=a^{2\cdot 2^i}=a^{2^{i+1}}$